# Supporting a single SVN repo across different folder hierarchies

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

So I have a project that ties together files and folders sprawled across my filesystem. Logically all of these files belong to a single project and therefore a single SVN repository, but I can't combine them into a single folder hierarchy because the programs involved are all hard-coded to save their source code to specific directories.

I don't think I'm the first one to deal with such a scenario, so I'm hoping that I'm overlooking a simple solution. I considered four approaches but they all have downsides; is there another approach that I haven't considered, or barring that, can anyone provide insight into the best approach long-term?

Here are the approaches I considered:

1. Checkout the appropriate subfolder of the SVN repo in each system folder. Probably the simplest technically, but I don't like that a lot of separate commits become necessary to constitute what might be a single "logical" commit. Same with updates.
2. Keep a SVN checkout in a single spot and use a program to sync the SVN hierarchy and the system folders. Makes SVN usage a little simpler, but it's more moving parts. It's also pretty easy to overwrite uncommitted work if someone syncs in the wrong direction.
3. Single SVN checkout, use junctions/symlinks to the system folders. Based on my attempts and some web searches, this appears to be technically impossible at this time. It also feels a little fragile.
4. I might be able to go the opposite way and change the hard-coded program folders so that they are symlinks/junctions to subfolders of my SVN checkout. That still seems a little fragile: software updates might replace the symlink, or one or more of the programs might not like symlinks either.

Please note that some of the people that will be working with this repository are not developers, so I'd like to keep things as simple as possible for them. Also note that this is a Windows environment, and we typically use TortoiseSVN. Git/mercurial/etc are not an option, company policy requires SVN to tie in with our release process.

Going by the "simplest thing that could possibly work" approach, #1 seems like the way to go. But maybe (hopefully?) there is something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has weighed in on this I'll simply say that I did end up choosing door #1. That "solution" is simplest for a newcomer to understand, with nothing subtle that could break and cause harm or confusion. Multiple commits can get a little annoying, but I have found in practice that we're usually only updating/committing one or two locations at a time anyway.

It's also worth noting that some IDEs can abstract this issue away. If your IDE supports projects or solutions that pull files in from disparate locations, it's likely that SVN plugins for it do too. Visual Studio + AnkhSVN can handle it, for example--Ankh will simply split your "single" commit into multiple real commits to SVN. Doesn't really apply to my scenario, but maybe it will help someone else out.